# how to start an embeded video with the youtube iframe-api

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I am new to coding and I am trying to learn how to use the youtube IFRAME to control embded videos. The following code is mostly from youtube's api documentation. The only thing I added were the buttons and event listeners that are attached to them.

Can someone explain to me why "play" button that I have created can't start the video?

```js
  // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '250',
          width: '300',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }
     

    document.getElementById('pause').onclick = function() {
        player.pauseVideo();
    };
      
      
    document.getElementById('play').onclick = function() {
        player.playVideo();
    };
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div><button id= "pause">Pause</button></div>
    <div><button id= "play">Play</button></div>
    
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the documentation of the iFrame API is either outdated or completely wrong.

The function which should initialize the player **onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()** will never fire thus a click on the play/pause buttons won't work because the variable **player** is *undefined*.

To workaround this, you have to wait until the script you're loading into the freshly created `<script>` element has finished loading and inside the callback function you need to initialize the YT component by a call to it's own ready() function. This isn't mentioned anywhere.

Well, get rid of the complete onYouTubeIframeAPIReady function and replace it with this:

```
tag.onload = function() {

  YT.ready(function() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '250',
      width: '300',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      }
    });
  });

};
```